# Как изменить csv?

Tags: python, csv

Работает на чтение, но не меняет значение в файле:

```
import csv

directory="C:\\Users\\pyth\\output_3.csv"

with open(directory, 'r+') as f:
    d_reader = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter='\t')
    for row in d_reader:
        if float(row['Open']) > float(row['Close']):
            row['CLINE_TYPE'] = '1_MIN'
        else : row["CLINE_TYPE"] = '1_MAX'
```

Как написать на Pandas вложенные операторы ветвления?

Цель: найти строки следующие друг за другом с разницей 5 минут, при условии где в первой строке open > close, а во  второй  open < close или в первой строке  open < close, а во второй open > close.

Пример из жизни: в каких двух днях прошлого года температура утра вчерашнего дня было больше температуры вечера вчерашнего дня , а температура вечера следующего дня больше температура утра следующего дня или наборот.

Логика: Из входных данных, нужно отобрать пару строк, которые удовлетворяют следующим условиям: 1) между строками разница 5 минут по полю "OPEN TIME" (то есть следующая подряд) 2) если в первой строке значения в полях "OPEN" строго больше значения поля "Close", то на второй строке OPEN  строго меньше CLOSE, или наоборот. Если, условия выполняются, то записывается значения времени в переменную date_cline_up в случае "CLOSE" > "OPEN", date_cline_dow в случае "CLOSE" < "OPEN", и идёт запись в файл. Далее цикл ищет вторую пару строк удовлетворяющие условиям. Если, условие не выполняется, то значения date_cline_up или date_cline_dow перезаписываются в Nan, в зависимости от того какая первая строка была первой в паре или в каждой последующей паре. Из входных данных получается следующие строки выполняют условия: строки 0-1 будут содержать надпись в поле CLINE_TYPE -'1_MAX', и в строках, 2-3 1_MAX. Код в "полное условие" полностью покрывает описанную логику.

Входные данные :

```
    Open Time   Close time  Open    Close       STATUS  CLINE_TYPE
0   2021-11-06 13:25:00 2021-11-06 13:29:59.999000064   60534.13    60509.9         
1   2021-11-06 13:30:00 2021-11-06 13:34:59.999000064   60509.89    60570.01        
2   2021-11-06 13:35:00 2021-11-06 13:39:59.999000064   60570.01    60469.34        
3   2021-11-06 13:40:00 2021-11-06 13:44:59.999000064   60469.34    60546.6
```

Полное условие:

```
date_cline_up=None
date_cline_dow=None

for row in d_reader:
    curent_date = datetime.strptime(row["Open Time"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if date_cline_up is None and date_cline_dow is None:
        if float(row["Open"]) > float(row["Close"]):
            date_cline_dow = datetime.strptime(row["Open Time"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        elif float(row["Open"]) < float(row["Close"]):
            date_cline_up = datetime.strptime(row["Open Time"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    elif date_cline_up is None and date_cline_dow is not None:
        if (((curent_date - date_cline_dow).total_seconds()) % 3600 // 60) == 5 and float(row["Open"]) < float(row["Close"]):
            row["CLINE_TYPE"] = '1_MIN'
        else:
            date_cline_dow = None
    elif date_cline_up is not None and date_cline_dow is None:
        if (((curent_date - date_cline_up).total_seconds()) % 3600 // 60) == 5 and float(row["Open"]) > float(row["Close"]):
            row["CLINE_TYPE"] = '1_MAX'
        else:
            date_cline_up = None
```

Comment: почему бы не воспользоваться Pandas - код будет короче, понятнее и работать будет быстрее

Comment: @MaxU делал изначально на pandas, не смог придумать как написать вложенное условие if без использования iterrows(). Приложил рабочий пример кода в "полное условие".

Comment: вы можете дополнить вопрос описанием логики и выходными данными, которые вы хотите получить? Из вашего кода непонятно откуда берутся `date_cline_up`, `date_cline_dow` до начала цикла и что они обозначают

Comment: @MaxU Описал логику, и изменил входные данные для наглядности. Переменные date_cline_up, date_cline_dow описал и представил в коде.

Comment: Попробуйте описать простыми словами вашу цель, вместо описания работы вашего алгоритма )

Comment: Добавил цель и  аналогичный пример из жизни.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131222/discussion-between---and-maxu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос...

Сначала добавим вспомогательные столбцы со значениями из "следующей" строки:

```
df[["Open2", "Close2"]] = df[["Open", "Close"]].shift(-1)
```

получилось:

```
In [13]: df
Out[13]:
            Open Time                    Close time      Open     Close     Open2    Close2
0 2021-11-06 13:25:00 2021-11-06 13:29:59.999000064  60534.13  60509.90  60509.89  60570.01
1 2021-11-06 13:30:00 2021-11-06 13:34:59.999000064  60509.89  60570.01  60570.01  60469.34
2 2021-11-06 13:35:00 2021-11-06 13:39:59.999000064  60570.01  60469.34  60469.34  60546.60
3 2021-11-06 13:40:00 2021-11-06 13:44:59.999000064  60469.34  60546.60       NaN       NaN
```

теперь можно фильтровать:

```
In [15]: df["Open Time"].diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(300).eq(300) & (np.sign((df["Open"] - df["Close"]) * (df["Open2"] - df["Close2"])) < 0)
Out[15]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

In [16]: df[df["Open Time"].diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(300).eq(300) & (np.sign((df["Open"] - df["Close"]) * (df["Open2"] - df["Close2"])) < 0)]
Out[16]:
            Open Time                    Close time      Open     Close     Open2    Close2
0 2021-11-06 13:25:00 2021-11-06 13:29:59.999000064  60534.13  60509.90  60509.89  60570.01
1 2021-11-06 13:30:00 2021-11-06 13:34:59.999000064  60509.89  60570.01  60570.01  60469.34
2 2021-11-06 13:35:00 2021-11-06 13:39:59.999000064  60570.01  60469.34  60469.34  60546.60
```